# Code for google's repo but gives error ->Failed to resolve: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.0'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

/*The above part of the code is there in the actual program*/

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'

    // Google
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'

    // Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0 .0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'

    // Firebase UI
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Is there any question here at all? [ask], [mcve]

Comment: How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Well If you look at [releases](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), there isn't a 10.0.0 version. Only 10.0.1 and the recommended 10.2.0.

Also looking at the [setup](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) guide, app indexing isn't listed as one of the individual packages gps offers (though I'm not saying definitively that it does not exist), so maybe you should use the core package.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```